# Get referrer from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to collect url data (Page 1: google.com/chicken-pot-pies , for example) from page 1 and when a user clicks on a link to page 2 (Page 2: google.com/chicken-pot-pies2), the url from page 1 is loaded with page 2 (so page 2 url will look like: google.com/chicken-pot-pies=chicken-pot-pies2/)?

Here's the JSFiddle for the onclick event from page 1 that I want loaded on page 2 as well: http://jsfiddle.net/34zY4/2/

```
q1=iPoTouch&amp;x=79&amp;y=2
```

Sorry if I didn't elaborate properly.

Comment: Are you hoping to add the current _query string_ parameters to the new link? POST data is not included in the query string; that is GET data.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking to do @SamR

Answer (score 0):

you can create form and submit this form use **submit()**;

```
<form action="https://www.domain.com" method="post" id='myData'>
    <input type="hidden" name="code1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="code2" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="code3" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="code4" value="4">
</form>
```

Next

```
 $("#myData").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

From page 2 on the client side, you can use something like:

```
document.referrer
```

However, to dynamically change the URL (Routing) you will want to use some server side logic.  For C#, MVC is a nice approach.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=814

I believe the specific URL you are looking for won't work (if you remove the final "/", you're fine).

Comment: How would I implement the 'document referrer' method so that it's included in the url of page 2?

Comment: document.referrer wouldn't change the URL, but it would allow you to access the URL of the referring page. Depending on *why* you need the query string parameters, calling document.referrer may be adequate for your purposes. If you need the same parameters to persist across multiple page changes, that will not work for you.

Comment: @SamR I just want the url of page 1 to show on page 2. I don't want a different url

Comment: When you say "URL", do you mean the entire URL, or just the query string? Edit: It's possible to use the History API to make one page appear to be another page, but it comes with the side effect of not reflecting where you actually are, so copying the "display" URL and pasting it into another window will *not* get you back to the same place.

Comment: @SamR I mean just the string

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. You can stop a link click and change or completely replace the URL. I did this a few years ago to append a token.

```
var idx = loc.indexOf("?");
 if (idx !== -1) {
    this.href += (this.href.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&amp;" : "?") + 
        loc.substring(idx+1);
 }
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_sir/34zY4/4/).

You may need to add a class name or some other check if you have both on-site and external links on the page, or you may mess up URLs leaving the site, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: So I just put this javascript on page 2 and it will collect the url from page 1?

Comment: This script has to be on Page 1. If you don't control Page 1, there are still a couple of options, but it depends on _why_ you want the the parameters. Do you want the second page to make the request to the server with the same query string, or do you need the query string for some client-side logic?

Comment: If you look at my current fiddle there's a strings that's produced on another page. I want that string from that page to show up on a different page as well if that makes sense.

Comment: i.e. Page 1: has a link and it's clicked on |
     Page 2: contains a string and has a link that's clicked as well |
     Page 3: i want the string from page 2 to show up on this page (page 3)

That should clear things up?

Comment: OK, the fiddle I provided above should work. It needs to be included on _each page_, because each page will have to update the URL of the page you are _about_ to go to so it will have the query string parameters when you arrive. If there are any problems or more questions, please ask.

Comment: I've applied the code as directed but it doesn't seem to function.

Comment: When I click the link to the next page it doesn't show the string of the previous url

Comment: Did you use the complete example from the fiddle? You may also need to wrap that in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`  http://jsfiddle.net/_sir/34zY4/4/

Comment: Yes I wrapped it and put it on the next 3 pages but the string doesn't append itself to the url of the following pages. I want page 2 string to append itself to page 3 string when a user clicks next. Is this possible?

Comment: You added the code to each of the pages, and it still didn't persist the query string? Are they clicking a button or submitting a form rather than clicking a link?